# Android video-like animation, how to create?

Tags: android, android-animation

In this mock up, see the screen where it said "Decrease Traffic", the traffic light pops up from below.

https://dribbble.com/shots/2106573-Intro-App-Interaction

I'm wondering how to create that effect on Android, if possible, any library to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with [Android Property Animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

in your example it seems to be a scale animation from 0 to 1 in x and y direction.
you can also combine different animations to get such or other effects.

Comment: if you look to the following screen, "Decreasing pollution", the trees appear later than the bottom rock. So must I do animation for 2 separate drawables (one is the bottom rock), then the trees?

Comment: correct, with an animatorset you can define which animations should be performed at the same time and which should be performed one after another. so for each part of the animation you'll need a separat image.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that these kind of animation are to develop with a 3rd party program, and are not done by Android itself.

This way you have a ready-to-instantiate file (.gif maybe?) that you just call when the view pager is switched.

Looking also to the other animations in the example (look @ "Meet New Friends", how every circle pops by himself) I think this was the used approach in your example-link.

If you are anyway looking for something that would look like what is done there, I'd suggest you start playing around Animator objects (and its subclasses like Value/ObjectAnimator) to animate the view you want.

This can be done also via XML files, describing the animation you need.

An important role in this do-it-yourself animation is played by Interpolators , who give you the chance to further customize the animation in an easier way (take a look at OvershootInterpolator, which lets your animation go a bit after the destination value you set, just to turn back later, giving you a "blob" effect. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMOJxBe9KGg) might give a better idea what I'm meaning)